# "unrecognized selector sent to instance error" when first edit address field then come back to datetime picker

Tags: ios, swift2, unrecognized-selector

I am working on a simple interface like this:

[image: add event]

The time, duration, phone, and address are all UITextfield, while when click on Time UITextField, an inputview of UIDatePicker would come up to allow choose date and time.

The problem is if I edit the **address text field**, then come back to the **Time textfield** which would pop up UIDatepicker, the application would crash with error:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception         'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[WantFun.AddEventViewController dateTImeInputPressed:]
:   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x137001f30'
```

There would be no error if I edit the duration or phone which are indicate to be number, but each time when I edit the address then I would have error if try to go to input the time form.

And here is my code:

```
class AddEventViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    let timeString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

    datePicker.text = timeString

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: Action

@IBAction func dateTimeInputPressed(sender: UITextField) {
    let inputView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 240))


    let datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0))
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    datePickerView.minuteInterval = 5

    inputView.addSubview(datePickerView) // add date picker to UIView

    let doneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (100/2), 0, 100, 50))
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

    inputView.addSubview(doneButton) // add Button to UIView

    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "doneButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) // set button click event

    sender.inputView = inputView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    handleDatePicker(datePickerView) // Set the date on start.
}
func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    datePicker.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}

func doneButton(sender:UIButton?)
{
    datePicker.resignFirstResponder() // To resign the inputView on clicking done.
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Any reason for that error? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like address textfield has attach a incorrect event. Have you checked "Sent Events" of Address textfield in IB (Connection Inspector)?

Comment: @disepulv, you are right, while right click the address filed, it is wried to see a wrong action has attached to it, the "dateTImeInputPressed" action. No idea when it has been added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any chance that you have typo somewhere in your code/xib/storyboard? Exception says that it can't find selector `-[WantFun.AddEventViewController dateTImeInputPressed:]` (capital I in Time) and your class has method `dateTimeInputPressed`

Comment: The action were created by control drag "time UITextField" to code, and input with the action name 'dateTimeInputPressed', I didn't type it anywhere else. The name in the code is right, no idea why the error would come with that typo error. But if just click on the time UITextField, the UIDatePicker can pop up and choose the date and time successfully, I don't think if really a typo error would allow to succeed even in the beginning.

Comment: I have had same error and have solved it by change the font of the `placeholder` of `UITextField` because I choosed a `font` that never exist in Xcode then I realized it. Here is the error log  `-[NSNull pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1069ca180`